# form element verification JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, verification, if-statement

Hi all I have a form that has 4 fields
I can get it to check if any field is empty and change the background color with no problem, but the problem I am getting is if all the fields are not empty it's not continuing with the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitpw").click(function(){
var un = $("#FirstName").val();
var pw = $("#LastName").val();
var sid = $("#StudentID").val();
var ss = $("#LastFour").val();
var unl = un.substring(0,un.length - un.length + 1);
var pwl = pw.substring(0,pw.length - pw.length +4)
var emptyTextBoxes = $('.information').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
emptyTextBoxes.each(function() {
if ($('.information:empty'))
{
$(this).css("background-color", "red");
alert("Please Enter Information in the Red Fields");
}
else
{
("This is the part that never triggers!!!")
alert("it worked");
$("#campusun").html(unl+pwl+sid+ss);
$("#campuspw").html(sid+ss);
$("#emailun").html(unl+pwl+sid+"@live.tcicollege.edu");
$("#emailpw").html(sid+ss);
}
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it will never trigger. You're basically grouping together a set of elements from `$('.information')`, say you get 3 elements. The `each` method is going to invoke the callback on each element; since `$('.information')` had to be non empty to even invoke the callback, and your code for that check *is in the callback invoked*, it never satisfies the condition.

It sounds like you want to do this:

```
 if(emptyTextBoxes.length == 0)
 {
      alert("it worked");
      $("#campusun").html(unl+pwl+sid+ss);
      $("#campuspw").html(sid+ss);
      $("#emailun").html(unl+pwl+sid+"@live.tcicollege.edu");
      $("#emailpw").html(sid+ss);
 }
 else
 {
      emptyTextBoxes.each(function()
      {
          $(this).css("background-color", "red");
          alert("Please Enter Information in the Red Fields");
      });
 }
```